# Page Break lines won't stay off for a shared Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a shared Excel document on my NAS, and in Excel I go to options and disable Page Break lines.

However, when someone else opens the document, the page breaks reappear. When I reopen the document in Excel on my computer after someone else has opened it, they are back for me as well.

I've had everyone turn off Page Breaks, but that didn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

We're using both Excel 2010 and 2007.

Comment: I am unable to duplicate it on our network. Is there a possibility someone still has that feature turned on and is saving the document that way? Does it still happen if you save it and reopen it from the same computer? Does it only happen between different versions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press `Alt+F11` and find the `ThisWorkbook` object for the workbook in question.
2. Double click on the `ThisWorkbook` object.
3. Paste the following code there:

`Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Sh.DisplayPageBreaks = False
End Sub`

4. Save as a macro-enabled workbook.